# Regression testing Issue [make installcheck]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

#### For the regression tests:

After running `make installcheck` on `my_extension` getting error:

```
echo "+++ regress install-check in  +++" && /Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/bin'    --dbname=contrib_regression my_extension--regress.sql
+++ regress install-check in  +++
(using postmaster on Unix socket, default port)
============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "spartacus" does not exist
command failed: "/Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/bin/psql" -X -c "SET client_min_messages = warning" -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \"contrib_regression\"" "postgres"
make: *** [installcheck] Error 2
```

How to solve this on macOS?

##### The code for the makefile is:

```
EXTENSION = my_extension
DATA = my_extension--1.0.sql
REGRESS = my_extension--regress.sql

PG_CONFIG  ?= pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

##### Regression testing SQL file `my_extension--regress.sql`:

```sql
-- regression test script for my_extension

-- Create the my_table table
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Test the my_function function
SELECT my_function();

-- Verify the data in the my_table table
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Tried to set the environment variable PGUSER
`PGUSER=postgres make installcheck`

Got the error:

```sql
echo "+++ regress install-check in  +++" && /Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/Users/spartacus/.pgenv/pgsql-15.0/bin'    --dbname=contrib_regression my_extension--regress.sql
+++ regress install-check in  +++
(using postmaster on Unix socket, default port)
============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
SET
DROP DATABASE
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== running regression test queries        ==============
test my_extension--regress.sql    ... /bin/sh: /Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/sql/my_extension--regress.sql.sql: No such file or directory
diff: /Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/expected/my_extension--regress.sql.out: No such file or directory
diff: /Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/results/my_extension--regress.sql.out: No such file or directory
diff command failed with status 512: diff  "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/expected/my_extension--regress.sql.out" "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/results/my_extension--regress.sql.out" > "/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/results/my_extension--regress.sql.out.diff"
make: *** [installcheck] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `PGUSER` so that the regression test tries to connect as the correct database user:

```bash
PGUSER=postgres make installcheck
```

or, in two steps:

```bash
export PGUSER=postgres
make installcheck
```

Comment: Getting the same error.

Used PGUSER statement above the REGRESS variable declaration.

Comment: I wrote "environment variable", not "makefile variable".

Comment: I corrected the makefile but am still getting an error(I have edited the main question to include the code).

Comment: For more information the code for the extension is 
- https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/Postgres-extension-tutorial/tree/main/Code/my_extension

Comment: `/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension/sql/my_extension--regress.sql.sql` was not found. Did you create regression tests? By the way, this is off-topic for this forum. Should be stackoverdlow.

Comment: I created a regression sql file whose code is given above.-> I have also created an issue on github maybe you could get more idea there 

https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/Postgres-extension-tutorial/issues/15

isn't this a DB-related problem, StackOverflow is for programming questions right?
I am new to this so i am just figuring this out.

Comment: Well, you are *developing* an extension. That's not really database administration.

Comment: You must create `my_extension--regress.sql` in the correct directory, as the error message says.